# Yii2 Natural Sorting

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have been scratching my head and cannot for the life of me work out how to do the following

I need a VARCHAR filed to be able to be sorted in gridview using natural sorting i.e. number in order

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `number`;
```

Is how the system works at present. and will out put this

```
# id, number
1, 1
206, 10
97, 100
98, 102
99, 103
103, 104
104, 105
105, 106
106, 107
107, 108
108, 109
10, 11
109, 110
110, 111
111, 112
```

In MySQL if i want natural ordering then i can write this

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `number`+0;
```

I then get

```
# id, number
1, 1
2, 2
3, 3
4, 4
5, 5
6, 6
7, 7
8, 8
9, 9
206, 10
10, 11
11, 12
12, 13
```

So the number is in order.

How can i achieve this in Yii2?

Regards

Liam

From the answer below i was able to use the following in the search model

```
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['number'] = 
    [
        'asc' => ['LENGTH(number)' => SORT_ASC, 'number'=>SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['LENGTH(number)' => SORT_DESC, 'number'=>SORT_DESC],
    ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in DataProvider configuration (I'm not sure if you can pass MySQL function instead of simple column name).

```
// ...
'sort' => [
    'defaultOrder' => [
        'LENGTH(number)' => SORT_ASC,
        'number' => SORT_ASC,
    ],
],
```

In general checking length first and value second should give you natsort effect.

Comment: I will try this shortly, Many Thanks